# How to run JQuery code when changing templates in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my project I would like for some code:

```
 $("#panelAccommodation").hide();
 $("#panelFlight").hide();
```

to run when changing templates. What I want is for these panels which have the ids (shown above) to be hidden when a user changes to the template they are on. They are supposed to only show when clicked on but that part of the code is already done with an action on the controller. Any ideas on how to do this?

EDIT:

I'm really sorry it seems I was misunderstood and it was my fault because I didn't specify it, when I said click I didn't mean on a button but on an option on a RadioButtonList.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than hiding and showing the divs, I'd suggest looking into rendering templates into named outlets, and sending actions with the {{action}} helper. More details about rendering [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/), and sending actions [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/).

So let's assume you have an index route and want to show accomodations and flights.

```
// app/routes/application.js

actions: {
  showAccommodationPanel: function() {
    this.render('accomodations', {
      into: "application",
      outlet: "accomodations"
    });
  },
  removeAccomodationPanel: function() {
    this.disconnectOutlet({
      outlet: "accomodations",
      parentView: "application"
    });
  }
}
```

And you have an accomodations template:

```
// app/templates/accomodations.hbs

<panel id="panelAccomodation">
  <h1>
    All you awesome panel markup here
  </h1>
  <button {{action "removeAccommodationPanel"}}>Close</button>
</panel>
```

then your main template:

```
// app/templates/application.hbs

{{outlet}}
{{outlet "accomodations"}}
<button {{action "showAccommodationPanel"}}>Show accomodations</button>
```

Comment: That was a really good answer thanks! but I'm not sure it would work in my specific situation, I've editted the question check it out if can please. thanks

Comment: Ok well you can still use most of my example, just combine it with some radio buttons: https://gist.github.com/vasilakisfil/d055d9d2d9b56f684b42